# How to add a column name inside a case_when when using mutate_all and across?

Tags: r, case, across

I have the following dataframe and I want to mutate all the columns in `ENV` dataframe to substitute  some value with `case_when` function:

```
  metrics <-
    structure(list(var = c("SST", "SSS"), min = c(-1.82623172259469, 
    0.0106425614590989), max = c(30.7357019713913, 62.4178951570953
    ), Q1 = c(29.6467844102333, 37.2283509056568), Q2 = c(25.0978897764037, 
    35.1366150711973), Q3 = c(1.08054073780591, 33.6817701728394), 
        Q4 = c(-1.75609879755353, 22.3324745864139), slope.L = c(-0.219833625638, 
        -0.478071840394898), slope.R = c(0.352529811255446, 0.0881111953059067
        )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
    ENV1<-
    structure(list(SST = c(-1.18181673490857, -1.29487169195505, 
    -1.2891296530063, -1.16459061806231, -1.02749131873705, -0.877831755030538, 
    -0.827006290249864, -0.87501492439503, -0.907842479642887, -0.925488955993432, 
    -0.928734689365441), SSS = c(34.4828464105725, 34.4536828344067, 
    34.4394813115398, 34.4402418419719, 34.4202143674095, 34.3793988878528, 
    34.3479811742902, 34.3259612267216, 34.2944239596526, 34.2533693730831, 
    34.225624174873)), row.names = 30:40, class = "data.frame")

ENV1 |> mutate_all(funs(
  case_when(
    . < metrics[metrics$var == x,]$Q1 ~ 0,
    . <= metrics[metrics$var == x,]$Q3 ~ 1,
    . > metrics[metrics$var == x,]$Q4 ~ 0
  )
))
```

I have the issue with what to put instead of `x`? I tried using `names(.)`  , a name of a column ( so it takes a value from a `metrics` dataframe. But it does not work. I also tried colnames(.), vars(.), as.character(.) - with no luck

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Should `x` just be `SST` and `SSS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cur_column()`

```
ENV1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
  ~case_when(
    . < metrics[metrics$var == cur_column(),]$Q1 ~ 0,
    . <= metrics[metrics$var == cur_column(),]$Q3 ~ 1,
    . > metrics[metrics$var == cur_column(),]$Q4 ~ 0
  )
))
```